# Power failure while updating bios

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I'm new here and don't know how should I ask for help. My apologies .
I was updating bios to 5.90 form 5.20 and while updating I faced load shedding issue and pc turned off (73% done).
After that turned power on and nothing shows on monitor (it's not posting anything on monitor). I got random code on led which is located on motherboard. Led shows me few random code changing and F2 then F9 and it shows forever.

May be my motherboard bricked.

PC Specs:
Ryzen 7 1700
Asrock Fatal1ty X370 Gaming X
G.skill flarex 3200 Mhz 8GB
Corsair MP510 250 GB
Asus ROG Strix RX580 OC 8GB

my question is :

1. How can I restore bios?
2. where is the bios chip situated? (my friend said if found he can flash the chip)
3. can I flash the chip using "BIOS_PH" header? if so which device/cable/programmer need to use. Also what is the correct pin diagram of "BIOS_PH" header. ( my friend told me to ask)

Current situation:
For the COVID-19 pandemic we are in lockdown situation. every service center is close now. and the the lockdown period is not mention yet.
I'm a full time freelancer and I need to fix the motherboard asap. I can't effort new one now.

Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: “Is my motherboard bricked?” - Probably; “How can I restore bios?” - Does your motherboard have dual bios? Check the specifications for your motherboard.  “what is the model of bios chip?” - You will have to edit your question and tell us this information

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your comment. no my motherboard don't have dual bios. Actually I don't know the chip model. I tried to find the but failed.

Comment: Start a support ticket, see what Asrock says>>>>https://event.asrock.com/tsd.asp

Comment: They said - "Install one stick RAM on each slot by turns to repeat suggestion 2 to check if the problem relates to a specific RAM stick or slot."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to do a flashback without an existing working Bios.

Bios location image:
[Bios location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSdzo.png)

BIOS_PH header pinout guide: [SPI Flash Header pinout](https://www.overclock.net/threads/spi-flash-header-pinout-for-use-with-8-pin-spi-flashing-tools-such-as-ch341a.1643534/)

Otherwise you can pick up a preprogrammed chip from eBay but you'll need soldering skills to replace the chip as it's not housed in a socket.

Comment: I found the chip model. It's MX25U12873F. Can I flash this chip using an external SPI programmer (CH341A based programmers)?